# Distortion from Sound Blaster Z after switching to headphones with 4 pole jack

Tags: audio, sound-card, headphones, headphone-jack

I bought new headphones that have a 4 pole jack, to replace a headset with split audio and mic jacks (both 3 pole).

My PC has a Sound Blaster Z with mic and headphone ports. The old 3 pole headset worked fine, but my new headphones experience distortion when connected to the card directly, but are fine with my monitor and phone.

Do I need some type of splitter to connect these headphones to the card?

Comment: Short answer: Yes. Long answer: Why would you expect a 4 pole jack to work in a socket that expects 3 poles?

Comment: @DavidPostill Well, that was deeply unhelpful.

Comment: Whatever. Sometimes the truth is unhelpful.